# Right before you, I make my mark

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> My first part is a journey to embark
>   The other is two of a kind
>   Right before you, I make my mark
>   The answer you shall find

Who am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My first part is a journey to embark

> **quest** - a  journey in pursuit of a goal

The other is two of a kind

> perhaps **ion** - there are two types, positive and negative, of these charged atoms or molecules

Right before you, I make my mark, The answer you shall find, Who am I?

> question - this is before us, has a question mark, and is found by an answer?

Comment: And you just found the answer, Tom!